# What is the meaning of round complexity in distributed network algorithms

Tags: time-complexity, distributed-computing

Can someone explain what is the meaning of the time complexity in distributed networking algorithms? The definition given in [DNA book by Panduranga](https://sites.google.com/site/gopalpandurangan/dna?authuser=0) is as follow :

"In the synchronous model, time is measured by the number of clock ticks called rounds, i.e., processors are said to compute in “lock step”. When running a distributed algorithm, different nodes might take a different number of rounds to finish. In that case, the maximum time needed over all nodes is taken as the time complexity"

Can you explain the above definition with a simple example

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to compute the sum of a really large list (say, 1 billion numbers). To speed things up, you use 4 threads, each computing the sum of 250 million rows, which can then be added to get the total sum. If the time taken for each thread to run is:

```
thread1 takes 43 seconds
thread2 takes 39 seconds
thread3 takes 40 seconds
thread4 takes 41 seconds
```

Then you would say that the runtime of this operation is bounded by the thread that takes the longest, in this case 43 seconds. It doesn't matter if the other threads take 2 seconds, the longest task determines the runtime of your algorithm.